# Why is the full screen mode not working on the website but works fine in dev mode

Tags: flutter, dart, youtube-player-flutter

I'm using youtube_player_iframe: ^4.0.4 to stream my youtube video. When I launch my web app from my main.dart the full screen option works perfectly. I put my site online and the full screen doesn't work there. Can someone help me with this issue please?

Here is the code for the video :

```
 content: SizedBox(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.75 * 300 / 500,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.75,
        child: YoutubePlayer(
          controller: YoutubePlayerController.fromVideoId(
              params: const YoutubePlayerParams(
                  showFullscreenButton: true, showControls: true),
              videoId: YoutubePlayerController.convertUrlToId(ref
                      .watch(videoListProvider.notifier)
                      .get(ref.watch(currentId))
                      .link)
                  .toString()),
          aspectRatio: 300 / 500,
        )),
```